# How to deep link to nested navigators in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My navigation structure is as follows:

```
const App = () => {
  const prefix = 'test://';
  return <AppNavigator uriPrefix={prefix} />;
};

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  splash: SplashScreen,
  auth: AuthStack,
  main: HomeStack,
});

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  landing: LandingScreen,
  login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    path: 'page/login',
  },
  register: {
    screen: RegisterScreen,
    path: 'page/signup',
  },
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  home: HomeScreen,
  details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
    path: 'details/:assetId',
  },
  upsell: {
    screen: UpsellScreen,
    path: 'page/upsell',
  },
});
```

My deep linking URI are:

```
test://page/login
test://page/signup
test://details/12345
test://page/upsell
```

On linking to any one of these URIs, I am always taken to the `SplashScreen` which is the first screen of my app. How do I link to nested navigators properly and link to the correct screen?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation it looks like you also need to set up Android and iOS native part to make it works correctly.

It is described here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html#set-up-with-react-native-init-projects